# Getting an error when trying to use set iam policy method in gcp to update cloud storage policy using python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-kms

Getting an error when trying to add encrypter decrypter role to the bucket service account. Below is the code.. Any idea what's missing?

```
storage_client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials)
sa_name = storage_client.get_service_account_email("project name")
print(sa_name)

bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("bucket name")
policy = bucket.get_iam_policy(requested_policy_version=3)
policy.version = 3
policy.bindings.append({
    "role": "roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter",
    "members": {"serviceAccount:{}".format(sa_name)}
})
bucket.set_iam_policy(policy)
```

```
**Error:** google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 PUT https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucketname/iam?prettyPrint=false: Role roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter is not supported for this resource.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message **XYZ is not supported for this resource** means that you are trying to grant a permission (role) to a resource that does not use that permission or does not provide a resource, such as a KMS key, upon which that permission can be granted.

In your question you are trying to grant the permission **roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter** to a Google Cloud Storage **bucket**. You have the logic reversed, you would modify a KMS resource policy, such as a key instead of a bucket resource policy. Refer to the following link for more details on binding to a KMS resource:

[KMS: Granting roles on a resource](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/iam#granting_roles_on_a_resource)